# Print Preview shows "Document does not contain any pages" instead of the document

Tags: c#

I am trying to set up an application in VS2013 with Page Setup, Print Preview and Print. The issue I am having is instead of seeing the page in the Print Preview window, all I see is  "Document does not contain any pages." Everything I find on the Internet is regarding opening a file and printing/previewing it. I want to be able to print/preview unsaved text in a Rich Textbox.

Here is what I have:

```
PageSetupDialog psdlg = new PageSetupDialog();
PrintDialog pdlg = new PrintDialog();
PrintPreviewDialog ppdlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
```

Event handlers:

```
private void pageSetupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        psdlg.PrinterSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
        psdlg.PageSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
        psdlg.EnableMetric = false;
        psdlg.ShowNetwork = true;
        pd.PrinterSettings = psdlg.PrinterSettings;
        psdlg.ShowDialog();
        if (psdlg.PageSettings != null)
        {
            pd.DefaultPageSettings = psdlg.PageSettings;
        }
    }

    private void printPreviewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ppdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pd.DocumentName = strCurrentFile;
            ppdlg.Document = pd;
        }                
    }

    private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             
        if(printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler (pd_PrintPage);
            pd.Print();
        }
    }
```

PrintPage Event Handler:

```
private void DocumentToPrint_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(rtbMain.Text);
        float LinesPerPage = 0;
        float YPosition = 0;
        int Count = 0;
        float LeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        float TopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        string Line = null;
        Font PrintFont = this.rtbMain.Font;
        SolidBrush PrintBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        LinesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

        while (Count < LinesPerPage && ((Line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            YPosition = TopMargin + (Count * PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Line, PrintFont, PrintBrush, LeftMargin, YPosition, new StringFormat());
            Count++;
        }

        if (Line != null)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
        PrintBrush.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Do you handle the `PrintPage` event anywhere? If so, you need to include that code. If not, well...you should.

Comment: There's still nothing in your question that shows where that method is subscribed to the event.